# How to uncompress/decrypt raw tcp data?

Tags: java, tcp, wireshark

I'm trying to look at some data that is being sent to my local application. When i look at the TCP packets in wireshark all i see is raw TCP data...
[image]

From what i've gathered it seems like it's using some sort of encryption. Is there any way to find out how to decrepit it to read the data inside?

Here's a larger sample hex dump

```
00000000  17 03 03 00 50 13 31 eb  c1 49 10 81 4f a6 ee 04   ....P.1. .I..O...
00000010  00 c9 c4 d6 50 a1 37 ff  74 9a 30 73 69 03 39 92   ....P.7. t.0si.9.
00000020  65 58 a3 46 68 9e 85 f8  28 85 7e c4 2d 1b 5f ea   eX.Fh... (.~.-._.
00000030  22 3d 35 47 db 0c e7 a0  dd 18 72 fe 5f c8 20 70   "=5G.... ..r._. p
00000040  67 5c 98 cb d5 b9 8b 55  13 a8 0d fb 90 ce ab 4d   g\.....U .......M
00000050  b6 67 50 f7 73                                     .gP.s
00000055  17 03 03 00 50 86 d9 02  f1 41 df 04 50 f2 64 60   ....P... .A..P.d`
00000065  cc 7e 11 57 36 0c 51 40  e4 87 09 01 bf ac 8c 6b   .~.W6.Q@ .......k
00000075  ed 61 42 f5 61 2d d9 00  11 b5 03 65 c6 b7 09 12   .aB.a-.. ...e....
00000085  93 cf db f7 4f b6 9a 97  b0 97 7d b6 09 ba 7b bb   ....O... ..}...{.
00000095  a8 30 34 f2 6e 32 8e ca  b4 e7 81 46 4a e9 56 e6   .04.n2.. ...FJ.V.
000000A5  5d 2d b1 d4 69                                     ]-..i
000000AA  17 03 03 00 50 72 f9 60  9d 27 ae 99 f4 22 97 3f   ....Pr.` .'...".?
000000BA  da c9 e4 04 87 8c 99 b9  85 f0 bd b0 ab 53 9b 55   ........ .....S.U
000000CA  69 fe e4 fd 95 51 bc 93  9e d3 df c3 08 eb cf 87   i....Q.. ........
000000DA  b8 f5 fe 58 56 16 5e 57  a1 87 65 84 2c bf c4 01   ...XV.^W ..e.,...
000000EA  a9 a0 c6 6f 68 0a b3 a8  3b 96 d3 85 47 b6 a3 af   ...oh... ;...G...
000000FA  56 ac 87 e2 c2                                     V....
000000FF  17 03 03 00 50 98 de 10  d8 ef e3 21 3d fc 80 54   ....P... ...!=..T
0000010F  34 4e 88 52 b0 88 d1 c8  ed b1 5b e0 6b aa 08 49   4N.R.... ..[.k..I
0000011F  e5 ec 98 f1 fb cc a6 0e  30 69 9d e3 c3 9e 36 a4   ........ 0i....6.
0000012F  bc 78 36 b1 41 80 82 0c  0f 98 6e 6c 64 b0 43 55   .x6.A... ..nld.CU
0000013F  4a 17 1c fd 89 8b 80 28  54 bb 5d 1d 86 af b5 30   J......( T.]....0
0000014F  60 00 30 2d 02                                     `.0-.
00000154  17 03 03 00 50 21 64 38  5b a5 87 e4 e9 5f a5 88   ....P!d8 [...._..
00000164  82 83 32 6f 53 39 d2 42  6e 5c a7 0f df 7b 1b ee   ..2oS9.B n\...{..
00000174  0c a2 6d 1a 30 60 ca aa  5a 42 20 03 e7 af 69 bf   ..m.0`.. ZB ...i.
00000184  7e 91 b1 0f 62 52 b5 ff  dd ba e2 3b 1f f3 dc ca   ~...bR.. ...;....
00000194  f1 6e 0d 99 f6 91 c6 54  fb b3 8b 11 38 5e d6 19   .n.....T ....8^..
000001A4  22 58 cd a0 61                                     "X..a
000001A9  17 03 03 00 50 01 f6 d6  a4 7b 5b 71 73 29 e8 21   ....P... .{[qs).!
000001B9  fa 55 c0 26 77 43 41 12  be 52 2b d0 8d dd 03 8c   .U.&wCA. .R+.....
000001C9  bc 64 d0 16 b0 51 7a e3  d2 fe 10 41 24 0e be c1   .d...Qz. ...A$...
000001D9  99 bb 7d 3e 07 3f f0 9d  00 5a 58 57 c2 17 c1 c6   ..}>.?.. .ZXW....
000001E9  fd 99 5a 78 aa af 31 e0  e0 80 37 4b 31 e6 14 41   ..Zx..1. ..7K1..A
000001F9  92 08 4d a8 a1                                     ..M..
000001FE  17 03 03 00 50 a9 d7 94  93 8a e2 e1 6f e0 c2 92   ....P... ....o...
0000020E  74 7c 02 0f 07 9b f2 fc  99 8e 00 1a 38 d3 0b ae   t|...... ....8...
0000021E  5f 2a e7 ff 23 94 b8 d7  a8 3a 44 c5 15 85 6c 31   _*..#... .:D...l1
0000022E  91 7e ff 78 36 80 ee 77  d1 2f 2b 44 f9 89 35 a8   .~.x6..w ./+D..5.
0000023E  ed 24 87 61 2a ca f4 6f  97 ce fb ea fb 1f 9e df   .$.a*..o ........
0000024E  2e fe 71 e7 40                                     ..q.@
00000253  17 03 03 00 50 90 80 df  3c 8e 07 38 ef 42 6a 2d   ....P... <..8.Bj-
00000263  ae 04 b8 c2 2b cf c6 73  5e 11 a0 52 bc e2 64 ac   ....+..s ^..R..d.
00000273  c5 9b 45 fc 31 5e eb b9  b9 e3 5c 74 00 b0 60 27   ..E.1^.. ..\t..`'
00000283  6a 00 59 5b 3c 3f 56 19  34 45 82 ef 1a 4e f3 fc   j.Y[<?V. 4E...N..
00000293  2b 36 d5 ca 15 19 93 5f  21 ac 57 23 64 d0 ef 37   +6....._ !.W#d..7
000002A3  53 0a 85 07 34                                     S...4
```

Answer (score 4):

From the images it can be seen that the data starts with `17 03 03`. This could be the beginning of a TLS record, i.e. 0x17 (23) is the application_data content type and 0x0303 is the TLS version (TLS 1.2).

TLS data can only be decrypted if you have access to the keys used for encryption or if these keys can be derived. See [the Wireshark Wiki](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) on how to decrypt such traffic once you got access to the necessary data.

Of course it is possible that this a completely different protocol and that it only looked like the beginning of a TLS record in the single packet you've shown. There is simply too few context and details in the question to be sure.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mPU2497n does this help? And if it were TLS over TCP how could i decode it?

Comment: @BenArnao: please no hex dumps. You can publish the pcap file to cloudshark.org instead. But from a short look it looks like TLS since every packet starts with 0x170303, i.e. TLS 1.2 application_data. As for how to decode TLS see the link to the Wireshark Wiki I've included in my answer.